# Show context-menus only when certain elements are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am kinda stuck with something and I need your help.

I am trying to show context-menus only when a user right-clicks on a certain elements in the page.

I thought I solve this problem by using getElementByClassName(...) and adding an onClick listener to each one of the elements, and when the user clicks on any of them I will then create the context-menus. And then remove the content menu later when everything is done.

Problem is that I don't have the full class names of those elements, all I know that they start with "story".

I am not sure how to go about doing this. Is there a way to use regex and getting all elements with a class name of story? Or is that not possible.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There's [this library](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/) that allows for regex selectors.

```
<div class="story-blabla"></div>

$("div:regex(class, story.*)")
```

However, you may not want to implement a full library. There's another solution:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return this.class.match(/story.*/);
    })
```

This will return the objects you want.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with pure javascript. I managed to get everything done in this project without using jquery, would like to keep it that way. With that said, beggars can't be choosers :P, I will check your solution out.

Comment: Well, IE doesn't support [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName), but check out the last example in that link.

Comment: tried your answer `$('div').filter(function() { return this.class })` returns an empty list, as a result I cannot use match. `$('div') return our the div classes though as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [attribute starts with selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp)

`document.querySelectorAll("[class^=story]")`